# UltraVNC giving Server closed connection

Tags: ultravnc, vnc-viewer

I've just installed UltraVNC version 1.0.9.6.2 on a Win 7 desktop machine, and also on a Win 2008 R2 server.  I've configured them both for single domain MS Login.

Whichever way I try to connect (desktop -> server or server -> desktop), the connection is made, but then immediately says "Server closed connection  -The server running as application" (which it's not- the server is running as a Windows Service under the Local System account on both machines.)

I've googled this issue and found a few suggestions on the forums, but they didn't seem to help.

Looking at the application logs, I'm seeing a an exception c0000005 in SAMCLI.dll being called from WinVNC whenever I'm attempting to logon.  I'm sure that's the problem, but I have no idea what the source of the exception is, nor what to do about it. (This does appear to be related to the Windows Login authentication - it will work if I turn Windows Login off and just rely on VNC login.)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using VNC when the RDP protocol is much more efficient, already built-in to both pieces of software you're talking about, and directly tie into user account authentication? VNC is way more bloated than RDP because it takes full bitmaps of the screen, whereas RDP instructs your local system on drawing the windows itself; it leads to lower network usage and a more responsive experience. Honestly I recommend you consider switching to RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol / Terminal Services)

Comment: Except that terminal services locks the physical console of the machine being used, making it useless for training or support where you need someone to see what you are seeing.  Use cases make a difference.

Comment: @artoon that isn't a stated purpose of the original post, as such isn't necessarily relevant.